# How can I set a custom icon for a folder?

Tags: 10.10, nautilus

Some folders in my Home directory have special icons.

[image]

I would like to do something like this with a custom icon for a folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on the folder and click properties:

[image]

Click the button with a folder icon:

[image]

Now browse to find the icon you want to use and click 'Open':

[image]

The folder will now use the custom icon:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Righ click on your folder for which you want to change the icon and select properties.Click the folder icon,browse for new icons in your system and then set it.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Right click on folder → Properties, in opened window click on folder icon and just choose a new one.