# How can I change the folder icon in Nautilus with a command?

Tags: nautilus, themes, icons, settings, appearance

I know how to change an icon [this way](https://askubuntu.com/q/16299/46531). Also [that](https://askubuntu.com/q/52430/46531) doesn't work for folders inside Nautilus, but for application launchers.

---

What I'm looking for is an equivalent to changing the icon for an application in the launcher, i. e. the *Home* folder, via

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop
```

[image: change home icon]

That way you can **set an icon *type***, which is helpful when you later want to change the icon set resp. theme or when you want the best resolution for each size of the icon.

So, I know how I can do this for applications in the launcher - but how can I realize this for icon folders in `Nautilus`? (In which file these settings are stored and editable with i. e. `Gedit`?)

---

For example, I try to change the folder icon for *~/.wine/drive_c*. I want to use this Faenza icon (I use Faenza-theme, the icon is called *folder-wine.png*):

[image: wine icon]

I want it to appear in best resolution: smaller as bookmark in Nautilus' sidebar, bigger as folder icon when I search Unity's dash. Using the scalable *svg* is *not* a solution, because it looks slightly different from the equivalent *png*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change the special folder icons (xdg user directories), you'll have to change them by making a custom theme. They are set to a specific name which is provided by the theme, and based on which folders are set as your Music, Documents, Videos, etc… folders.

To set a custom icon name to use from the theme, for the `~/.wine/drive_c` folder for example, you can run the following in a terminal:

```
gvfs-set-attribute ~/.wine/drive_c metadata::custom-icon-name folder-wine
```

This should make Nautilus use the `folder-wine` icon. However, this icon will **not** be used in GTK+ file selectors or other applications. To unset the custom icon name, you can run the following in a terminal:

```
gvfs-set-attribute -t unset ~/.wine/drive_c metadata::custom-icon-name folder-wine
```

Note, that if you've previously set a custom icon on the file, within Nautilus directly, you'll have to unset that icon. You can do this by opening the properties dialog for that file in Nautilus, clicking on the button with the icon on it, and choosing "Revert" in the file chooser dialog which opens up.

Comment: @vanadium Your edit has broken the answer (`file:///folder-wine` would expect a file named this in `/`, rather than using the icon name), I think. Also, I think the old information should be preserved with a note saying something like _as of GNOME 3.xx, use gio, and before that use gvfs_ or such.

Comment: You might be right. I rolled the edit back.