# Can I change the file icon with Gio?

Tags: python, development, gtk3, gobject

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the folder icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115845/how-can-i-change-the-folder-icon)

I'm using python. I want change a file icon with Gio from a python app. I found a lot of deprecated documentation and I'm not sure how I can do it.

I tried this, but nothing happen:

```
from gi.repository import Gio
f = Gio.File.parse_name('/home/my_user/Desktop/test.txt')
f.set_attribute_string("metadata::custom_icon", '/usr/share/icons/Humanity/animations/48/brasero-disc-100.svg', Gio.FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE, None)
```

Which class and method have I use? Any idea, please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think is not a duplicate, because I don't want use 'gvfs-set-attribute', because it's not refresh nautilus contents. By this reason I want use Gio :)

Comment: gvfs-set-attribute is merely a command line tool which does basically the exact same thing you are doing in your code. You can use it as a quick way to test, rather than editing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly a duplicate of a previous question I answered, but you have 2 problems with your current code:

- It is `custom-icon` and not `custom_icon`
- You really do not want to set the icon of a file to be a file from the animations context of a theme. Or in general, a file at all. It's better to set the `custom-icon-name` attribute if you really must, and then have that icon be a part of the theme, so that it works correctly if the user changes themes.

Comment: Thanks dobey! but I tried 'custom-icon' and 'custom-icon-name', and Nautilus is not changing the icon :( Any idea? Thanks in advance! :) http://paste.ubuntu.com/1202847/

Comment: You need to set custom-icon-name to just the icon name, such as "text-x-generic" for it to work. You may also need to refresh the view in nautilus, if you have the window already open and expect it to change immediately.