# How can I remove the gray boxes around custom folder icons?

Tags: nautilus, icons, customization, 13.04

When I [set custom folder icons](https://askubuntu.com/a/16302/1859) in Ubuntu 13.04, gray boxes appear around them:

[image: Home in Ubuntu 13.04]

How can I make the icons just look normal?

Comment: How did you set the custom icons? Did you make sure the icon files were formatted in either png or svg and set to a transparent background?

Comment: I used the method linked to above, and images I chose are SVGs in `/usr/share/icons/Humanity`.

Comment: I'm also annoyed by this... did you find a solution?

Comment: Despite being marked as fixed - this looks like its still a bug - or at least the version of nautilus in raring does NOT have the patch installed. - https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688808

Comment: I downgraded Nautilus to the latest version that came with Ubuntu 12.10. No gray boxes anymore.

Comment: Good find, @fossfreedom, this is a bug after all. An [upstream fix](https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?id=f69e47) was committed just after the 3.6.3 release so I assume we'll see it in time.

Comment: As per Meta policy (http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4216/how-should-we-deal-with-bounty-questions-that-are-confirmed-bugs) - since this is a confirmed bug report that may or may not be fixed in the near future, this question has been closed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. In Nautilus 3.6.3 (the version in Ubuntu 13.04) every custom icon gets a frame "to make it consistent with the appearance of thumbnails."

That's what I read in the [changelog on Launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/raring/nautilus/raring/filesg) (search for 2012-08-31, and you wil read it too.)

The 64x64 bits PNG-image that draws that frame, is included in the source code package. 
It's the thumbnail_frame.png in the /icons directory

SOLUTION(1): in the source-code, replace that thumnail_frame.png with another picture, and recompile the program.

SOLUTION(2): Hack the nautilus-ui-utilies.c file, starting at codeline 192

```
void
nautilus_ui_frame_image (GdkPixbuf **pixbuf)
{
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf_with_frame, *frame;
int left_offset, top_offset, right_offset, bottom_offset;

/*  frame = nautilus_get_thumbnail_frame (); */
    frame = NULL;
if (frame == NULL) {
    return;
}

left_offset = NAUTILUS_THUMBNAIL_FRAME_LEFT;
top_offset = NAUTILUS_THUMBNAIL_FRAME_TOP;
right_offset = NAUTILUS_THUMBNAIL_FRAME_RIGHT;
bottom_offset = NAUTILUS_THUMBNAIL_FRAME_BOTTOM;

pixbuf_with_frame = eel_embed_image_in_frame
    (*pixbuf, frame,
     left_offset, top_offset, right_offset, bottom_offset);
g_object_unref (*pixbuf);

*pixbuf = pixbuf_with_frame;
}
```

So with this hack the nautilus_ui_frame_image function returns without putting a frame :-)

Comment: Actually, its not an ambiance phenomena, but the way nautilus behaves and renders the icons. Irrespective of the theme, I am getting the border on custom icons. This is definitely **NOT** configurable via GTK CSS files.

Comment: Also, its quite visible from the attached screenshot in the question that the user is using Ambiance theme itself, and not some other theme.

Comment: The road to hell is paved with misjudgements, never with naked facts. So: it looks like Ambiance, but is it really Ambiance?

Comment: Can you add instructions for editing and recompiling the source?

Comment: Clear instructions about recompiling and rebuilding a package on this site: http://ariejan.net/2008/05/04/how-to-compile-packages-on-debianubuntu-by-hand/

Comment: changelog link is broken

Comment: Won't both of your proposed solutions interfere with actual image thumbnails, too? I don't want to remove the frames from thumbnails, just from icons—like how things were in Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

If you are like me that rarely have lucky compiling things by yourself, you may want something already compiled.

[Nemo](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?p=198) is a fork of Nautilus 3.4

You can install it with the [Cinnamon ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Regards ;-)

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a solution to this particular problem (I wasn't able to find one myself), you can work around it by not using folders with custom icons, but rather desktop files that are links to alternate locations (e.g. a hidden folder in your home directory).
Their icon will be shown without a border.

Example: `link.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Link
Name=MyFolder
URL=file:///home/<username>/.hidden_folder/
Icon=/path/to/icon.svg
```